# Clutter - high scene composition, performance and suggested practices

Tags: clutter, meego, clutter-gui

I am absolutely new to `Clutter` and `Cogl` and am supposed to work on an application, which will display rather large amounts of data (lists, endless menus, highly nested elements and more).

I have been working with many frameworks, especially on Windows like `WinAPI`, `WinForms`, `WPF` and know, that there is problem when creating custom components like `Lists` that display a lots of items using composition from already existing components (e.g. generating thousands of labels in the table to display list view).

**My question is how well does Clutter perform with that?**

Does it have some scene virtualization that will render only the necessary items in the viewport?

Does it have some composition layer that can handle high composition of Actors?

And by that, I mean an `Actor` containing a texture, three text actors and another two actors representing some buttons (probably also composed) and all this in some king of repeater.

I was unable to find any materials concerning this and don't have time to experiment on this so I am desperately looking for some advice.

If you are about to suggest me another framework/approach than please do not since `Clutter` is the only choice for me (system requirements, customer request, ...).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some measurements myself and it seems that Clutter can handle pretty deep and wide composition trees without causing any performance issues.
The problem I had was caused with improper allocation of items displayed in list, which were not deallocated properly.